# Regular expression for text followed by comma

Tags: regex

Hi I tried writing regular expression for below pattern

```
D123456789,D123456789,D123456789,D123456789,D123456789,D123456789,D123456789
```

The pattern should accept the first alphabet as `D`  followed by 9 digits with a comma. The last comma is not recommended.

My pattern is -

```
(^[Dd][0-9]{9}[,])+
```

Please guide me on how to do this?

Comment: Use [`^[Dd][0-9]{10}(?:,[Dd][0-9]{10})*$`](https://regex101.com/r/3UJsAn/1)

Comment: Note that in your example pattern, all occurences have 10 digits, not 9.

Comment: I have corrected my question.  It's supposed to have 9digits .

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribizew thanks for the pattern this worked out.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to match each `D` or `d` followed by **exactly**
9 digits (no more), so it is not enough to write `/D\d{9}/gi`,
as it would have matched this `D` and **initial** 9 digits from
a longer digit string.

The proper regex should contain also a **positive lookahead**,
including either a comma or the end of string. Something like:

```
/D\d{9}(?=,|$)/gi
```

I assume that you are not "interested" in the `,` after the digits, so
I didn't include it in the match.

Note also that your source sample contains **10**-digit strings (not 9).
Did you make a mistake in this detail?

Comment: Yes , it&#39;s supposed to have 9 digits . I have corrected my question .